# "on app push, do"

Tags: heroku

Is there any realtime API functionality which would allow me to know when an application has been pushed and completed? I didn't see anything in the documentation. Essentially, I'd like to write an add-on that could receive push events and than do something with them (trigger selenium tests, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [deploy hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks). The [HTTP POST hook](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#http-post-hook) is the most versatile one.

Comment: Missed that. Perfect! Thanks.